# Howto fix Backgroundcolor bleeding in bordered ToolStripStatusLabel

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a problem with a `ToolStripStatusLabel` which occurs when the `BorderSides` is set to `All` and I set a Background Color different to the owning `StatusStrip` Background Color:  The ToolStripStatusLabels Backgroundcolor bleeds outside the border - which looks pretty ugly. I tried to set the `BorderStyle` property to other settings than Flat without success.

In the screenshot added below, you see the issue - the example in teal is with `BorderStyle = Adjust` to get the border drawn outside the rectangle. But unfortunately the border dissappears completely.

[image: Different BorderStyles won't help]

What I would like to get is no bleeding at all like in this hand-drawn example.

[image]

Is this possible to do by a setting or by inheriting or overriding a specific method of the `ToolStripStatusLabel`? I'm open to programmatical solutions, but I don't know where to start from, so any hints would be welcome.

## Implemented Solution by combining [x4rf41](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656081/2455604) and [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656608/2455604)s answers below

Since I made use of multiple answers which led me on the right track, I added the final solution to the question.

I extended the `ToolStripStatusLabel` class and overrode the `OnPaint` method. This gave me the possibility to make use of the classes properties and draw it as it would draw itself normally but without the bleeding.

```
public partial class ToolStripStatusLabelWithoutColorBleeding : ToolStripStatusLabel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bugfix to prevent bleeding of background colors outside the borders.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle borderRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);

        // Background
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), borderRectangle);

        // Border (if required)
        if (BorderSides != ToolStripStatusLabelBorderSides.None)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle, BorderStyle, (Border3DSide)BorderSides);

        // Draw Text if you need it
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 0,0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your problem can be solved by setting the labels properties. You have to do some custom drawing.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with your labels but the easiest way for custom drawing is to use the paint event of the label:

```
private void toolStripStatusLabel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Use the sender, so that you can use the same event handler for every label
    ToolStripStatusLabel label = (ToolStripStatusLabel)sender;
    // Background
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(label.BackColor), e.ClipRectangle);
    // Border
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
        new Pen(label.ForeColor),  // use any Color here for the border
        new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.Location,new Size(e.ClipRectangle.Width-1,e.ClipRectangle.Height-1))
    );
    // Draw Text if you need it
    e.Graphics.DrawString(label.Text, label.Font, new SolidBrush(label.ForeColor), e.ClipRectangle.Location);
}
```

this will give you your hand-drawn example if you set the BackColor of the label to magenta and the ForeColor to the right gray.

You can also extend the ToolStripStatusLabel class and override the onPaint method. The code would be pretty much the same, but you have more options in the custom class, like adding a BorderColor property or something like that.

Comment: I decided to extend the class and override the OnPaint method as suggested, using the ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D method because it keeps the same color as when not overridden. I've added this to the OP and accepted your answer because it led me to the right path.

Comment: Just wanted to inform you, that I fixed the part of your solution by not relying on e.ClipRectangle anymore - since the size of ClipRectangle is not always the size of the client area (e.g. if you move the window outside the screen). I now use the actual width and height of the control and it works just fine. Could you update your answer as well to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I played around a little using `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D` and found that it too has the BackColor showing as a bottom and right line.

So, similar to xfr41's answer, I tried to do owner-drawing. My idea was to use the system's routines, but to enlarge the drawing rectangle over the clipping area; this way the wrong stripes are lost altogether..

```
private void toolStripStatusLabel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = e.ClipRectangle; 
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(r.X, r.Y, r.Width + 1, r.Height + 1);
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, r2 , Border3DStyle.SunkenInner);
}
```

Comment: i like the ControlPaint because it uses the default system colors, but that also means you can't change it. what i want to know is why you call base.OnPaint in the event handler, isn't that the Form.OnPaint method?

Comment: Whoops, it had slipped in, corrected. - Yes it will use the system colors and thus stay in 'color-synch' with the rest of the system's color scheme. Not so good if you want complete freedom.. It also has the full range of 3DBorderstyles at each OS version. Hopefully. (But if the cut-off trick will always work is another question..)